# Using ACF to grab Lat/Long based on other Address Information?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I created AFC fields for street address, city, state, and zip and then I am using Google Maps to take the information in those fields and then populate two other ACF fields with the lat and long for that address. The issue I am having is that when I put in the address fields and click the publish/update button it does not grab the lat/long right away. When I click it a second time is when the grabs the lat/long and populates those ACF fields. This only occurs when I add a new address. If I use an address that has already been used on another post and reuse that same one for a new post it does grab the lat/long on first try. So based off of that I assume that the first click is grabbing the lat/long and the second click is being used to populate the lat/long fields.

But what I need to accomplish is that both of those steps(grabbing lat/long and populating lat/long fields) to happen on the same publish/update button click. Below is the code I currently am using:

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_start', 'qd_fake_publish_button' );

function qd_fake_publish_button()
{
  $screen = get_current_screen();
  if( ($screen->parent_base == 'edit') && ( $screen->id == 'opportunity' ))
  {
    print '<button id="acquireLatLong" class="button button-primary button-large">Publish</button>';
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'project_pins_save_post', 11);

function project_pins_save_post() {
  $screen = get_current_screen();
  if( ($screen->parent_base == 'edit') && ( $screen->id == 'opportunity' ))
  {
    $script = '
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function AcquireLatLont() {
        var mygc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var qd_street = document.getElementById("acf-field_5abe83dfda81b").value;
        var qd_city = document.getElementById("acf-field_5abe4bea43cc3").value;
        var qd_state = document.getElementById("acf-field_5abe4bf543cc4").value;
        var qd_zip = document.getElementById("acf-field_5abe4bfb43cc5").value;
        var address = qd_street + ", " + qd_city + ", " + qd_state + " " + qd_zip;
        mygc.geocode({ "address": address }, function (results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            document.getElementById("acf-field_5abe845fda81c").value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById("acf-field_5abe846ada81d").value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            document.getElementById("publish").click();
          } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
          }
        });
        return false;
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
      jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        $("#acquireLatLong")[0].textContent = $("#publish")[0].value;
        $("#acquireLatLong").click(function() {

            AcquireLatLont();

        });
      });
    </script>
    ';
    echo $script;
  }
}
```

Haven't really worked with populating ACF fields dynamically before, so not sure where this code snippet is messing up.

Comment: Why are you not using the ACF Google Map field? It captures all of this for you.